# Lenovo Z50-70 realtek dirver RTL7823BE wi-fi does not connect

Tags: wireless, lenovo, realtek

My Wi-Fi driver, I think, is not functioning properly on my Lenovo Z50-70 using a Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

After connecting to a wireless network it works for a brief period of time, then, although it shows a stable connection, I can't access any website whatsoever.

I tried the Wi-Fi on Windows 8.1 and it worked perfectly.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I read in other forums that there are no current Ubuntu WiFi drivers for our Realtek card built in on the Lenovo Z50-70. I have been dealing with the same problem for the last week, also running Ubuntu 14.04 on a z50-70 Lenovo laptop and go to the conclusion it will only run properly when running Ubuntu 13.X (or reset laptop by every time the connection fails).

Comment: Hello Wild Man. I have run the script from the link you provided. It provides an output but I am unaware of the information I should gather from it. Could you please provide more hints? I mean, I can read the information from this output file but I do not know what to do with it next. 
Best regards.

Comment: I have same issue. How did fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue after lot of research and facing kernel panic issues. Here is how I fixed it.

**Note** This can be used for installing any realtek wireless driver

`lspci | grep Network`

**Note**: If in this process you get **kernel panic** issue. **DONT PANIC** Solution for it is at the end. You dont need to re-install Ubuntu.

1. Upgrade linux kernel
2. Install following

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic

   git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
   cd rtlwifi_new
   make clean
   make

   sudo make install

   sudo depmod -a

   sudo modprobe rtl8723be

   echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
   ```
3. Reboot

**Sources:**

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1320070/comments/29
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1320070/comments/30

**Kernel panic**
If you run into kernel panic issue where the system does not reboot

1. Reboot into recovery mode
2. Log in with root
3. Mount file system in read write mode

   ```
   mount -o rw,remount /
   ```
4. Add the driver that you just added to the blacklist

   ```
   vim /etc/modprobe/blacklist.conf
   ```

   Add line `blacklist rtl8723be`
5. Reboot