# Wifi not working Ubuntu 14.04, no wifi detected

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

My wifi is not working or detected in the nm-tool.

here is the necessary information 
http://pastebin.com/Utt3iMg4

Comment: The answer to the question http://askubuntu.com/questions/524020/lenovo-z50-70-realtek-dirver-rtl7823be-wi-fi-does-not-connect# works perfectly nice for lenovo z50-70.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to the question [Lenovo Z50-70 realtek dirver RTL7823BE wi-fi does not connect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524020/)… works perfectly nice for lenovo z50-70. in ubuntu 14.04

1. update kernel is essential I guess.